# How to retrieve Tweeter name by Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

I have retweeters id's how to get Tweeter name by this id using Twitter API?

```
<?php
  Array ( [0] => 1969622664 [1] => 1860839948 [2] => 418367090 )
?>
```

Comment: Make your question more clear.

Comment: I am using twitter api by (https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and these id's above for some tweeters i need by this id's to get there names

Answer (score 0):

Use would use the `users/show` endpoint to get the user's `screen_name` from their id. Here is the doc: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show